# Android button shape drawable margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-drawable

Im styling a button using a shape drawable, this causes the button to over expand a little or lose it's margin so it doesnt align well with the other buttons. any idea why:

[image]

This is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:weightSum="2" >
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowMem"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="B" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="C" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonred"
            android:text="D" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the shape drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>

    <shape>
         <gradient
    android:startColor="#FFFF0000"
    android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
    android:angle="45"/>

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the below figure.. The default button is 9 patch image so there is always extra space after the button, This is the capture of your button. So when you set the background resource the empty space is filled by the image. So Better use `ImageView` instead. It will work perfectly with the imageview. Although there might be solutions like padding but they will fail in some situtation. You can implement the functionality with the ImageView. I hope this will help you.

[image: Default Button]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like each button has some dp of padding or layout marging.

Try to set

```
android:padding=0
```

If that does not work

```
android:layout_margin=0
```

This will eliminate the margin from the default buttons, if you want to solve the other way, add margin to the custom button

Answer (score 0):

That probably is because the canvas of the other drawables might have a padding.

Check the canvas padding[not the one you set in xml but the one that designers set in the image itself] and match it with your new drawable and see if they are the same. They should be the same.

Comment: where can i see that value?

Comment: Just open each image in a image editor like photoshop/gimp and check the size and any transparent paddings they might have.

Answer (score 0):

Try with my below layout i have done some relevant changes:

> ```
>  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
>   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
>   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>   android:orientation="vertical" >
>    <TableLayout
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_height="0dip"
>       android:layout_weight="1"
>       android:stretchColumns="*"
>       android:weightSum="2" >
>   <TableRow
>     android:id="@+id/tableRowMem"
>     android:weightSum="1" >
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/buttonA"
>             android:layout_width="0dip"
>             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_weight="0.5"
>             android:text="A"/>
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/buttonB"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5"
>         android:text="B" />
>
> </TableRow>
>
> <TableRow
>     android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
>     android:weightSum="1" >
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/buttonC"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_weight=".5"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:text="C" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/buttonD"
>         android:layout_width="0dp"
>         android:layout_weight="0.5"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:background="@drawable/buttonred"
>         android:text="D" />
> </TableRow>
> </TableLayout>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: the layout is a bit different, but again, same issue

Comment: Explain me how do you want your buttons to be arranged ?

Comment: exactly how it looks in the image i've uploaded, i want all the buttons to have the same height/width and should expand as much as possible.

Comment: you mean to say that its getting expanded when you apply the drawable ?

Comment: yes, setting the background in your layout also make the red button misalign

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to button.

```
android:padding="0dp"
```